# Is there any way I can make a Jupyter notebook script work as an (i)python script?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I saved a Jupyter notebook script as a python script and tried to run it by using ipython in a powershell, it works although it does not display the graph with the related subplots.

This is the code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from IPython import get_ipython
get_ipython().run_line_magic('matplotlib', 'inline')
#%matplotlib
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 1)
ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 2)
ax3 = fig.add_subplot(2, 2, 3)
plt.plot(np.random.randn(50).cumsum(), 'k--')
_ = ax1.hist(np.random.randn(100), bins=20, color='k', alpha=0.3)
ax2.scatter(np.arange(30), np.arange(30) + 3 * np.random.randn(30))
plt.show()
```

As anticipated the code runs, but I don't get the desired outcome, that is the automatically plotted graph. I can make it work when interactively coding on the powershell or directly on the Jupyter Notebook, but not this way. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: show your coding powersell, I need to see what it returns

Comment: comment out the `get_ipython` line.  You want to show the figure in a separate window, not the shell's.